# Vertx Future Object returns null

Tags: vert.x

```
public Future<String> getString(){
    Future<String> data = Future.future();
    postgreSQLClient.query("select * from test", resultSetAsyncResult -> {
        if(resultSetAsyncResult.succeeded()){
            List<JsonObject> rows = resultSetAsyncResult.result().getRows();
            data.complete("Completed...");
        }
    });
    return data;
}


Future<String> future = getString();
System.out.println(future.result());
```

This Return's null. Am I doing anything wrong here? I did also try AtomicReference, it returns null too. Confused.

Answer (score 4):

Vert.x `Future`, unlike Java `Future`, are not blocking.

In other words, when you write `future.get()` with a Java `Future`, it blocks the caller until the future completes, while `future.result()` with a Vert.x `Future` returns immediately, whether or not the future is completed.

Vert.x `Future` are not blocking because Vert.x code runs on event loops which must never be blocked.

If you want the result, set a handler

```
future.setHandler(ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    // get ar.result()
  } else {
    // deal with ar.cause()
  }
});
```

Comment: How about getting it by rxjava? Do you have any take on that?

Comment: RxJava makes sense if you need to combine sources of data/events or transform data on the fly. For simple use case, sticking with core Vert.x is fine.