# Vert.x return results and store them from a query MongoDB

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using Vert.x in my project, I used future() to get the results from a MongoDB query. However when I do future().result it returns "null". I want the result to be saved in the future and I will use it for other APIs. Is there any guide for me, I will be very grateful and appreciate if someone give me a solution. Thanks

router.class

```
rivate void getClazzById(RoutingContext rc) {
    
    Future<JsonObject> future = Future.future();

    String clazzId = rc.request().getParam("clazzId");
    classService.getClazzById(clazzId, res -> {
        System.out.println(res.result());
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            JsonObject result = res.result();
            if (result != null) {
                future.complete(res.result());
                rc.response().setStatusCode(200).putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .end(result.encodePrettily());
            } else {
                rc.response().setStatusCode(400).putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .end(new JsonObject().put("error", "Class not found!").encodePrettily());
            }
        } else
            rc.fail(res.cause());
    });
    
    future.setHandler(s -> {
        if (s.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("sss: " +s.result()); //  print: {"_id":"123", "name":"abc"}
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    });
    System.out.println("hhhhhh: " + future.result()); // I want to print {"_id":"123", "name":"abc"}

}
```

service.class

```
    public void getClazzById(String clazzId, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> resultHandler) {
    JsonObject query = new JsonObject().put("_id", clazzId);
    client.findOne(Collection.CLAZZ, query, null, ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                JsonObject result = ar.result();
                if (result == null) {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Error"));
                } else {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(result));
                }

            } else {
                ar.cause();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertx Future Object returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551722/vertx-future-object-returns-null)

Comment: You may also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325895/vertx-future-result-availability-and-coding-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing asynchronous code, you are carried to use the framework / runtime semantics and tools for communication.

You are already leveraging one of *Vert.x*'s way of async communication, the `Future` - but in the wrong manner trying to retrieve its result inline.

Instead of having the `Future` result accessed within your method, you need to return it as your mean of communication to a caller, which would be able to set a completion handler (`Handler`) to it:

```
private Future<JsonObject> getClazzById(RoutingContext rc) {
    
    Future<JsonObject> future = Future.future();

    String clazzId = rc.request().getParam("clazzId");
    classService.getClazzById(clazzId, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            JsonObject result = res.result();
            if (result != null) {
                future.complete(res.result()); // set the retrieved result
                rc.response().setStatusCode(200).putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .end(result.encodePrettily());
            } else {
                future.complete(null); // you need to provide 'null' result to avoid caller blocking
                rc.response().setStatusCode(400).putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .end(new JsonObject().put("error", "Class not found!").encodePrettily());
            }
        } else
            rc.fail(res.cause());
    });
    
    return future; // return the future to caller
}
```

An interested caller would be able to set a handler for `Future` completion as needed:

```
getClassById(rc).setHandler(s -> {
        if (s.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("sss: " +s.result()); //  print: {"_id":"123", "name":"abc"}
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    });
```

As a side note: you are not setting the API boundaries properly in your business logic as you are trying to resolve the HTTP `Response` result which generally denotes the request processing end while still returning the query result to be handled in some other manner.